# Exclude the values in "IN" clause

Tags: php, mysql

How should I exclude the values in "IN" clause?

```
    $Graduates = "45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,73,74,75,76,84,85,86,87,88,89,91,
         92,93,94,95,96,98,99,100,101,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,117,122,123,126,127,131,135,136,137,
         138,139,140,142,143,146,156"; //MajorID

    $QryFirstNursing = "SELECT *
                FROM ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll)."
                WHERE ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll).".MajorID IN (".$Graduates.")
                AND ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll).".Category = ".$CategoryIDN;        
    $resultFirstNursing = openQry($QryFirstNursing);
```

Please help guys. Thanks

Comment: Use `majorId Not In`

Comment: do you want to exclude specific values?

Comment: how do you get graduates ? you can do not exist if its a query that you use to get them, that would be most efficient  ie.. `... WHERE NOT EXIST ( SELECT id ... query to get graduate )`  Or even `NOT IN ( sql )` You may find this question helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702797/mysql-where-clause-which-excludes-results-in-subquery

Comment: just create an excluded graduates string and add another condition:
AND 2016MajorID NOT IN (".$excludedGraduates.")

Comment: I only want to query the data which is not included in the $Graduates variable that's why I'm looking for a solution that excludes $Graduates in querying the data.

Comment: um... `NOT IN( '.$Graduates.')` the `NOT` should give that away then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Ardit Meti rights. It look like this:

```
    $Graduates = "45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,73,74,75,76,84,85,86,87,88,89,91,92,93,94,95,96,98,99,100,101,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,117,122,123,126,127,131,135,136,137,138,139,140,142,143,146,156"; //MajorID

    $tableName = $SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll);

    $QryFirstNursing = "SELECT *
            FROM {$tableName}
            WHERE {$tableName}.MajorID NOT IN ('{$Graduates}')
            AND {$tableName}.Category = {$CategoryIDN}";        

    $resultFirstNursing = openQry($QryFirstNursing);
```